# Replace text inside an array in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an array in PHP $aResults full thousands of URLs that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => http://test.com/server1/Image?img=nortel.jpg ) 
Array ( [1] => http://test.com/server1/Image?img=network.jpg )
```

I need to replace the text inside each url and replace the server from server1 to server5 and the word image with photo so each url should look like this:

```
http://test.com/server5/photo?img=
```

How do i accomplish this?

I have tried a variation of str_replace functions but i cannot get this work:

```
$sImgURL = $aResults[1][0]; 
    $filter_url ='server1/Image';   
    $replace='server5/photo';
    $filtered_url = str_replace($filter_url, $replace, $aResults);
    print_r($aResults);
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using `foreach`?

Comment: Maybe instead of: `print_r($aResults);` do: `print_r($filtered_url);` ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 `http://test.com/server5/photo?img=nortel.jpg` is not what OP asked for.

Comment: `$arr = str_replace("/server1/Image", "/server5/Photo", $arr);` not good?

Comment: @Jessica That would make no sense if OP just wants an array full with: `http://test.com/server5/photo?img=` then he just could do: `array_fill(0, count($currentArray), "http://test.com/server5/photo?img=");` ...

Comment: I agree, but that's what he asked for.

Comment: I think this should be the prefix for all url's, which he wants to change, that's why he replaces it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($aResults); $i++) {
    $aResults[$i] = str_replace('server1/Image', 'server5/photo', $aResults[$i]);
}
```

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) also can take an array, so no need for a loop! (And this loop wouldn't even run correctly)

Comment: Of course, well spotted, I forgot it can accept arrays, that would be a much cleaner solution. On a side note, why would the loop not run?

Comment: As long as `$i++` is true your loop runs! That's until integer overflow and as long as you don't hit that you call `sizeof()` just for fun.

Comment: Aw semantics, okay I got two parameters the wrong way round hah, it's late, I'll swap them :)

Comment: Telling someone their code is incorrect is only useful if you also say why

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_map and str_replace functions:

```
<?php
    $data = array(
                0 => 'http://test.com/server1/Image?img=nortel.jpg' ,
                1 => 'http://test.com/server1/Image?img=network.jpg',
                2 => 'http://test.com/server1/Image?img=rk.jpg',
                3 => 'http://test.com/server1/Image?img=nek.jpg'
                );

    function foo($val){
        return str_replace(
            array('server1','Image'),
            array('server5','photo'),
            $val        
        );      

    }
    $res = array_map("foo",$data);

    var_dump($res); 
?>
```

As Rizier123 suggest, you can do it in one line by:

```
var_dump(str_replace('server1/Image','server5/photo',$data));
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need for this! `str_replace()` takes also an array as argument. So all these function calls are unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Put your values to 'find' and your values to 'replace' into arrays..

```
$find    = array('server1', 'Image');
$replace = array('server5', 'photo');

$newString = str_replace($find, $replace, $oldString);
```